# How to add an image above a link on hover?

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, hover

I have a navbar at the top of my page and I would like a rollover effect to occur where when you hover on a link, a light bulb icon appears directly above the link. What is the best way to achieve this with CSS?

```
.navbar .nav a, .navbar .nav .a {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.navbar .nav a:hover, .navbar .nav .a:hover {

   background-image: url('lightbulb.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: contain;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, we can better help guide you if you show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hello see above post edit. Thanks!

Comment: Can you also paste in some html, try to do a mcve, you can read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

To be sure of getting the light bulb exactly above the text I think I'd put your background code into a pseudo element so that it can be positioned on top of the text.

This simple snippet leaves some space above the element using padding - it all depends on how you want to do this in the real example of course with the positioning of navbar perhaps?

```css
a {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

a::before {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover::before {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp2LF.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<a href='#'>Hover</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 3rem;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2.5rem;
}

nav div {
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: calc(50% - 15px);
  top: -30px;
  display: none;
  background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/light-bulb-icon-vector-light-bulb-ideas-symbol-illustration-vector-id1167459261?k=20&m=1167459261&s=170667a&w=0&h=3KSKkFUNQoPvoS70bzIWeT1fXRuB9rzap6VC1HipCgg=');
  background-size: contain;
}

nav div:hover li::before {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>
    <li>List Item</li>
  </div>
  <div>
    <li>List Item</li>
  </div>
</nav>
```